# Laravel 5.4 500 internal server error on ajax with csrf field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to send json to laravel function with ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "{{ route('store-formbuilder') }}",
      type: 'POST',
      data: { payload: payload, _token: "{{csrf_token()}}" }
    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });
```

The payload looks like this:

```
{"fields":[{"label":"Text","field_type":"text","required":true,"field_options":{"size":"small"},"cid":"c2"}]}
```

my routes/web.php:

```
Route::post('/admin/formbuilder', 'FormBuilderController@store')->name('store-formbuilder');
```

and my store function in the controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Form;

class FormBuilderController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $fields = $request->fields;

            //foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $form = new Form;

                $form->name('test');
                $form->json($fields);

                $form->save();

                return response()->json(['success' => 'stana']);
            //}
        }

        return redirect()->route('formbuilder');
    }
}
```

When I try to send the ajax request it console logs error and it says 500 internal server error
I have the csrf token as you can see. I have no idea what the problem might be.
**NOTE:** I am using Laravel 5.4 if this might help

Comment: A 500 internal error means something is wrong in the code itself (usually syntax); check the log at storage/logs.

Comment: Have you seen preview of the 500 error in the network while inspecting ?

Comment: Could you paste the `Form` model?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out
Here are the things I did to fix it

I was incorrectly saving the properties of the model. It's not `$form->name('test')` it's `$form->name = 'test'` and same for the json.

The next thing that I needed to use `json_encode` on the fields so `$form->json = $fields` becomes `$form->json = json_encode($fields)` and I changed the name of the field payload in the ajax request which I am sending to fields so I `$request->fields` can access it